# How to send the result of a GET as a prop in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I have a Promise(GET) that will return a number. With this number from response I want to  set a state and send it to another component as props.
Now, the problem I encounter is that the promise gets resolved after the component that receives the props renders and I don't see the value.
The code is something like:

```js
interface State {
  number: string;
}

export class Form extends Component<State> {
  
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      number: config.EMPTY_STRING,
    };
  }
  
  async componentDidMount() {
    //fetch function sample
    await fetch
    .get(
      config.api.uri.getNumber(params)
      )
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ number: response.data })
        return response
      })
      .catch(catchError);
      
  }
  
  render(): ReactElement {
    const { state: { number }} = this;
    console.log(number);
    return <Component />
  }
}
```

After that I send the number from this component (C1) to another component(C2) as props and I log it again there.
What I see is that C2 renders first with number as undefined and then C1 renders with number from response.
What should I do in order to send the number to C2 ?

I am not very much into classes and I supposed that it might work properly with useEffect, in a functional component but I cannot change that.

Thanks a lot in advance for your patience and kindness.
Adi

Comment: What/where is "C2"?  Where are you sending any props to a component?  Given the code shown, it sounds like you're just asking how to send a prop to a component at all.  Which would look like this: `<Component someProp={number} />`

Comment: A fetch is async; components need to handle rendering before the fetch has completed. **Where** that's handled is up to you, e.g., dependent components can either not be rendered until the fetch is complete, they can handle rendering-before-data themselves, etc.

Comment: next time please include a properly formatted code paste. be mindful that you are asking people to donate their time to help you. these little things go a long way in getting you better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Comments inline with the code -

```js
export class Form extends Component<State> {
```

You can simplify the constructor by setting initial state directly in the class -

```js
  state = {
    number: config.EMPTY_STRING,
  }
```

Don't mix `async..await` with `.then` handlers. Instead assign the result of the awaited expression to a variable and use it directly -

```js
  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const {data} = await fetch.get(config.api.uri.getNumber(params))
      this.setState({ number: data })
    }
    catch (error) {
      catchError(error)
    }
  }
```

In your `render` method, check for the presence of the `number` state. If it is set, render the dependent child component, otherwise render an empty fragment. And don't declare types where typescript can automatically infer them -

```js
  render() {
    const { state: { number }} = this;
    return number
      ? <Component number={number} /> // number is set
      : <></>                         // number is not set
  }
}
```

Alternatively you could render a `<Loading />` component